# LUIS seperates words in german without logical rule

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

has LUIS a solution for German composite words like "SALAMIPIZZA" (engl: salami pizza)?
German instance separates words without any logical rule. "Apfelsaft" (engl.: apple juice) as example is not separated, but salami pizza it's.

Comment: Many words spelled wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-entities#list-entities) to account for this. For example, create list entity named "Foods", then a create a canonical form called "SALAMIPIZZA", and for that canonical form's list, enter in "SALAMIPIZZA" and "SALAMI PIZZA". This would also allow you to account for other spellings, such as "SALAMI-PIZZA".